# Unexpected Token When Appending Search form via jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to append a search form into my navigation bar in a wordpress site. I have to do this by writing javascript inside a script tag in the footer widget because I am not able to edit the actual source. However, I am getting an error in the console indicating `Unknown SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I cannot determine what I need to change to correct this error, however.

Here is the javascript I wrote which is being flagged in the console:

```
$mainNav.append("<li id='search'>
<form role='search' method='get' class='search-form form-inline' action='https://son.sites.unc.edu/'>
<div class='input-group'>
 <label class='hide'>Search for:</label>
  <input type="search" aria-labelledby='search site' value='' name='s' class='search-field form-control' placeholder='Search this site...'>
    <span class='input-group-btn'>
     <button type='submit' aria-labelledby='Submit' value='Submit Search' class='search-submit btn btn-default'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'>
      </span>
     </button>
    </span>
   </div>
</form></li>");
```

Comment: `type="search"` should be `type='search'` as nicely hilighted (the whole string needs to be on one line)

Comment: Oh cool, that didn't occur to me. Thank you, I got it to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Alex K. solved it for me:

`type="search"` should be `type='search'` as nicely hilighted (the whole string needs to be on one line)